# webGL draw 2D triangle with mouse click

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to draw a 2D triangle where mouse clicked.
Already made mouse event handler and could see the point where mouse clicked.
I wrote vertex position of Triangle in Buffer Object. It will be Triangle size.
How to connect the mouse event handler(function click) and position of Triangle(positionBuffer)
Could you give me answer?

```
     //Vertex shader program
  var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position = a_Position;\n' +

  '}\n';

   // Fragment shader program
  var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n' +
  '}\n';

function main() {
  // Retrieve <canvas> element
  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

  // Get the rendering context for WebGL
  var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
    return;
  }

  // Initialize shaders
  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
    console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
    return;
  }

  var n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
  if(n < 0){
    console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
    return;
  }


  // Register function (event handler) to be called on a mouse press
  canvas.onmousedown = function(ev){ click(ev, gl, canvas) };

  // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  // Clear <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}


var shapes = [];  // The array for the position of Triangle with mouse click

function click(ev, gl, canvas) {
  var x = ev.clientX; // x coordinate of a mouse pointer
  var y = ev.clientY; // y coordinate of a mouse pointer
  var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width/2)/(canvas.width/2);
  y = (canvas.height/2 - (y - rect.top))/(canvas.height/2);


  // Store the coordinates to shapes array
  shapes.push([x,y]);

  // Clear <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


  var len = shapes.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, shapes[i], gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  }
   // Draw
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}


//Make the BO for making triangle
function initVertexBuffers(gl){

  var vertices = new Float32Array([
     0.0, 0.1,
    -0.1, -0.1,
    0.1, -0.1,
    ]);
  var n = 3;

  //Create a buffer Object
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  if(!positionBuffer){
    console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
    return -1;
  }

  //Bind the buffer object to target
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  //Write date into the buffer object
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    //Assign the buffer object to a_Position variable
  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location  of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }

  //Connect the assignment to a_Position variable
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  //Enable the assignment to a_Position variable
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

  return n;
}
```

Error message->
[image: "image here"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want to happen. Do you want to draw one mesh with multiple triangles or do you want to draw N triangles?

In any case this code makes no sense

```
var shapes = [];  // The array for the position of Triangle with mouse click

function click(ev, gl, canvas) {
  ...    

  // Store the coordinates to shapes array
  shapes.push([x,y]);

  ...

  var len = shapes.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, shapes[i], gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  }
```

`gl.bufferData` requires a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), not a JavaScript native array of arrays which is what you're passing it.

But it's also not clear what you're trying to do. In `initVertexBuffer` you create a single buffer and upload a single triangle (3 vertices)

Then in `click` you try to replace that triangle in the position buffer with point data which if successful would delete the triangle. It's not successful because you didn't use a typed array but even if it was successful it wouldn't work because you'd have ended up deleting the triangle.

There's arguably too much wrong to really pick a place to start. I'd suggest [reading some other tutorials on WebGL](http://webglfundamentals.org)

Here is your code hacked to work

I added a uniform `u_Offset` to the vertex shader. Then I loop through your shape coordinates in `click`, set each recorded offset with `gl.uniform2f` and call `gl.drawArrays` for each triangle.

```js
     //Vertex shader program
  var VSHADER_SOURCE = `
  attribute vec4 a_Position;
  uniform vec2 u_Offset;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = a_Position + vec4(u_Offset, 0, 0);
  }`;

   // Fragment shader program
  var FSHADER_SOURCE = `
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }`;
  
  var offsetLoc;

function main() {
  // Retrieve <canvas> element
  var canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');

  // Get the rendering context for WebGL
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    console.log('Failed to get the rendering context for WebGL');
    return;
  }

  // Initialize shaders
  if (!initShaders(gl, VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE)) {
    console.log('Failed to intialize shaders.');
    return;
  }
  
  offsetLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, "u_Offset");

  var n = initVertexBuffers(gl);
  if(n < 0){
    console.log('Failed to set the positions of the vertices');
    return;
  }


  // Register function (event handler) to be called on a mouse press
  canvas.onmousedown = function(ev){ click(ev, gl, canvas) };

  // Specify the color for clearing <canvas>
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  // Clear <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}


var shapes = [];  // The array for the position of Triangle with mouse click

function click(ev, gl, canvas) {
  var x = ev.clientX; // x coordinate of a mouse pointer
  var y = ev.clientY; // y coordinate of a mouse pointer
  var rect = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect();

  x = ((x - rect.left) - canvas.width/2)/(canvas.width/2);
  y = (canvas.height/2 - (y - rect.top))/(canvas.height/2);


  // Store the coordinates to shapes array
  shapes.push([x,y]);

  // Clear <canvas>
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


  var len = shapes.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // Draw
    gl.uniform2f(offsetLoc, shapes[i][0], shapes[i][1]);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  }
}


//Make the BO for making triangle
function initVertexBuffers(gl){

  var vertices = new Float32Array([
     0.0, 0.1,
    -0.1, -0.1,
    0.1, -0.1,
    ]);
  var n = 3;

  //Create a buffer Object
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  if(!positionBuffer){
    console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
    return -1;
  }

  //Bind the buffer object to target
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  //Write date into the buffer object
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    //Assign the buffer object to a_Position variable
  var a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
  if (a_Position < 0) {
    console.log('Failed to get the storage location  of a_Position');
    return -1;
  }

  //Connect the assignment to a_Position variable
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  //Enable the assignment to a_Position variable
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);

  return n;
}

function initShaders(gl, vsrc, fsrc) {
  // initShaders is really poorly designed. Most WebGL programs need multiple shader programs
  // but this function assumes there will only ever be one shader program
  // Also you should never assign values to the gl context.
  gl.program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vsrc, fsrc]);
  gl.useProgram(gl.program);
  return gl.program;
}

main();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's what I want to make. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since your vertex shader is as simple as possible, the location of your triangle on screen is from -1 to 1 on X and 1 to -1 on Y (WebGL have positive Y up).

So, the following conversion should do the trick:

```
// convert mouse cursor to canvas top-left relative
x -= rect.left;
y -= rect.top;

// normalize with range -1 to 1 and invert Y
posX = (2 * (x / canvas.width)) - 1;
posY = (2 * ((canvas.height - y) / canvas.height)) - 1;
```

Comment: I changed my code as your answer but keep having error... Attached my error page image in the article.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with your triangle position. It is related to vertex buffer and pointer. I think you should structure your code another way, the way you use WebGL is not really the proper one. Be more sequential and "stupide" to begin (you'll optimize later): One "requestanimframe" loop, whithin the loop: bind buffer, set attrib pointer, draw. Outside the loop: update buffer data when mouse click.